# how to manage BLOB not via Azure

Tags: azure-blob-storage

we are currently working on a project to white label a cloud application.

what will be a proper application or add-on etc. to handle BLOBs ? 
i have looked into SQL server RBS add-on but it seems quite dead over there...
the solution should be MS oriented 
thanks Gilad

Comment: Can you help clarify more on what "White label a cloud application" means? What exactly do you want to do with Azure storage Blob?

Comment: tnx for your time.say we have Azure storage containing images and videos. Azure provide an api to handle these resources.add , delete , get url etc. i would like to find a non cloud solution to handle such resources (blob)

Comment: Sorry, but its still not clear to me. We expose these API's over Blob resource via REST using http/https. We also provide client libraries in various languages like .net, Java, node.js, android etc. Are you interested in learning about these client libraries so you don't have to deal with http directly? If not, can you provide more details?